# Print veritcal histogram without using arrays

Tags: java, histogram

I have to write an app which will get 3 numbers from user and create a histogram.
F.g: 
Input: 2, 4, 3
Output:

```
 *
 **
***
***
```

It's not that easy, because I can't use any array. I had an idea to find the biggest number and then create the loop

```
for(int i = max; i > 0; i--)
```

but I have no idea what to put in the loop.

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive question?

Comment: Can you reorder the histogram of must it follow the user input. For example 2,4,3 reorder to 4,3,2 so it become easier to print?

Comment: No, I can't reorder it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve it is to loop from the max down, as you were thinking, and just keep checking each number to see if it should print or not

```
void print(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
    for(int i = max; i > 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print(a >= i ? "*" : " ");
        System.out.print(b >= i ? "*" : " ");
        System.out.print(c >= i ? "*" : " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mrfk Define doesn't work well?  It should work as you requested

Comment: Well, my input was: 5, 3, 10. The first column had 6 *, the second 8 and the last only one.

Comment: @user3437460 since I pointed out that yours is almost an exact copy of mine, yes it would be similar

Comment: @Mrfk I'm running it on [compilejava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/) and getting the expected printout

Comment: Hm. Do you have any idea how to convert it into c++?

Comment: @Mrfk that'd a C++ question, but it should be very similar, just swap the `System.out.print`s with `cout << (a >= i ? "*" : " ") << (b >= i ? "*" : " ") << (c >= i ? "*" : " ") << endl;`

Comment: I see. Let me try it out

Comment: On c++ it works perfectly. I'll try to find what's wrong with java one, anyway thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
public static void histogram(int a, int b, int c){
    int size = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);
    for(int x=size; x>0; x--){
        System.out.print(x > a? " " : "*");
        System.out.print(x > b? " " : "*");
        System.out.println(x > c? " " : "*");
    }
}
```

First, determine the number of rows in the histogram by getting the maximum value out of the 3 integers.
Subsequently, print the columns. If it haven't reach it's given height, print a space, else print `*`.

Comment: This is an exact copy of my answer, except with an off by one error, each column will be 1 shorter than they should be

Comment: I only saw your code after I posted mine. It is indeed very similar. If I was not editing and testing my code in the IDE, I would have posted it much earlier ;)